# PHP membervariables DateObject modify

Tags: php, datetime, member-variables

In this code

```
$start = $this->getStart();
var_dump($start);
$start->modify('Monday this week');
var_dump($this->getStart());
```

-

```
public function getStart()
{
    return $this->start;
}
```

how is it possible, that the second dump actually shows the modified date?

I know that modify operates on the date object itself and not merely returns the new value. But why is the actual object property changed? When I change the value otherwise, e.g.

```
$start = $this->getStart();
var_dump($start);
$start = false;
var_dump($this->getStart());
```

two times the same date is dumped, as I would expect.

Comment: `$start` is a data member of some class. You can not modify it directly. Add code of `modify()` also.

Comment: The problem is the othert way around! If I modify $start, the member actually IS modified also! This is the weird thing that I'm asking about...